# Open an applet in Linux Terminal

Tags: java, linux, applet

My requirement is to open an applet in Linux terminal.

I have created a java class and a html file named A.java and A.html as follows:

#### `A.java`:

```
public class A extends Applet
{
    private int w, h;
    public void init( )
    {
            System.out.println(" in init");
            w = 45;
            h = 50;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
            g.drawRect(w, h, 20, 80);
    }
}
```

`A.html`:

```html
     <html>
        <p> This file launches the 'A' applet: A.class! </p>
        <applet code="A.class" height=200 width=320>
      </applet>
     </html>
```

When I try to execute it I get these errors:

```
[root@VMS e42]# appletviewer A.java
[root@VMS e42]# appletviewer A.html
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException:
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program       performed          an            operation which requires it.
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
    at sun.applet.AppletViewer.<init>(AppletViewer.java:159)
    at sun.applet.StdAppletViewerFactory.createAppletViewer       (AppletViewer.java:98)
    at sun.applet.AppletViewer.parse(AppletViewer.java:1158)
    at sun.applet.AppletViewer.parse(AppletViewer.java:1092)
    at sun.applet.Main.run(Main.java:156)
    at sun.applet.Main.main(Main.java:98)
```

What do I need to change?

Comment: You have to set the DISPLAY variable

Comment: *"My requirement is to open an applet in Linux terminal."* Why, to what purpose?

Answer (score 0):

The error message speaks for itself: you need to provide an X11 server (and set your `DISPLAY` environment variable to point to it).  Applets are AWT classes, and need a graphical display; you can't run one on an ordinary terminal.

As an aside, it's a bad idea to be running as root; it's an even worse idea to run X11 applications as root.